Can I set a long press button to control conveyor?
I'm making a manufacturing model.At the real world, the conveyor stop initially.When some man press the button, the conveyor run. I want to achieve that in Anylogic.
I've made an easy model like this:

I use the code conveyor.stop() at conveyorEnter block to make conveyor stop initially. And when I press the button, the conveyor run, and then stop.
But eventually, I want to make a long press button for the action conveyor.run().
Is there anyway to achieve that?

What do you mean by "Long-press button"?

Sorry for the confusion again.
A long-press button means:
When I press and hold the button, the conveyor runs.
When I release the button, the conveyor stops.

No you can't do this. When a button (or a shape) is clicked nothing happens, the action is executed only when you release the button. There is no available method to differentiate between clicking and releasing the button.
You can think of other methods, using a shape for example, you click it and change its color to red (as a simulation of the button being pressed) and click it again and turn it white (as a simulation of the button being released)

Not with buttons but you can use a Tickbox to tick/untick stuff.
